# Showing that $\binom{n}{r} \le 2^n$

Tags: combinatorics

How do we show that $\binom{n}{r} \le 2^n$ for any $r \le n \in \mathbb{N}$? I came across this combinatorial fact in a longer proof but couldn't think of an easy proof.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- $\binom{n}{r}$ is the number of subsets of a size $r$ of a set of
  size $n$. (By definition.)
- $2^n$ is the number of *all* subsets of a set of size $n$. (Proof: To
  specify a subset of the set, for each of the $n$ elements of the set,
  you have $2$ choices: whether to include it in the subset or not.)

The former is part of the latter, and the inequality is strict unless $n = 0$.

In fact, by the same reasoning, $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} = 2^n$.
(Which in turn is a special case of the binomial theorem $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}x^r = (1+x)^n$.)

Comment: Fantastic - thank you. The intuition behind it is very clearly explained and I understand it much better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:
$$
2^n = (1 + 1)^n = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} \ge \binom{n}{r}
$$
with equality only if $n = 0$